# Solution needed to a scenario

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make use of a column's value as a radio button's choice using below code

Forms.py

```
#retreiving data from database and assigning it to diction list
diction = polls_datum.objects.values_list('poll_choices', flat=True) 

#initializing list and dictionary
OPTIONS1 = {}
OPTIONS = []
#creating the dictionary with 0 to no of options given in list
for i in range(len(diction)):
    OPTIONS1[i] = diction[i]

#creating tuples from the dictionary above
#OPTIONS = zip(OPTIONS1.keys(), OPTIONS1.values())
for i in OPTIONS1:
    k = (i,OPTIONS1[i])
    OPTIONS.append(k)  

class polls_form(forms.ModelForm):    
    #retreiving data from database and assigning it to diction list

    options = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OPTIONS, widget = forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = polls_model
        fields = ['options']
```

Using a form I am saving the data or choices in a field (poll_choices), when trying to display it on the index page, it is not reflecting until a server restart.

Can someone help on this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course "it is not reflecting until a server restart" - that's obvious when you remember that django server processes are long-running processes (it's not like PHP where each script is executed afresh on each request), and that top-level code (code that's at the module's top-level, not in a function) is only executed once per process when the module is first imported. As a general rule: don't do ANY db query at a module's top-level or at the top-level of a class statement - at best you'll get stale data, at worse it will crash your server process (if you're doing query before everything has been properly setup by django, or if you're doing query based on a schema update before the migration has been applied).

The possible solutions are either to wait until the form's initialisation to setup your field's choices, or to pass a callable as the formfield's `choices` options, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices

Also, the way you're building your choices list is uselessly complicated - you could do it as a one-liner:

```
  OPTIONS = list(enumerate(polls_datum.objects.values_list('poll_choices', flat=True))
```

but it's also very brittle - you're relying on the current db content and ordering for the choice value when you should use the polls_datum's pk instead (which is garanteed to be stable).

And finally: since you're working with what seems to be a related model, you may want to use a `ModelChoiceField` instead.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference:

1. What version of Django are you using?
2. Have you read up on the documentation of ModelForms? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/
3. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `diction` to dictionary to tuple. I think you could skip a step there and your future self will thank you for that.
4. Try to follow some tutorials and understand why certain steps are being taken. I can see from your code that you're rather new to coding or Python and there's room for improvement. Not trying to talk you down, but I'm trying to push you into the direction of becoming a better developer ;-)

---

**REAL ANSWER**:

That being said, I think the solution is to write the loading of the data somewhere in your form model, rather than 'loose' in `forms.py`. See bruno's answer for more information on this.

If you want to reload the data on each request that loads the form, you should create a function that gets called every time the form is loaded (for example in the form's `__init__` function).

Comment: While the mention that putting this code at the module's top-level is the source of the problem is correct, this has actually nothing to do with compilation and .pyc files (cf my answer).

Comment: Like I noted, I was not certain on the details. Thanks for your answer and steering us in the right direction!